# empApi PushTopic channel does not exist after successful subscribe

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, streaming-api, pushtopic

I am trying to debug a flaky connection to a PushTopic. Usually it works and is rock solid, except when it doesn't. The connection is being made from LWC after importing lightning/empApi.

Occasionally the connection is made and then the subscribe result appears to be successful but an error comes through straight after the subscription response stating the channel does not exist

> {"clientId":"br1wx4d3pldq0dx1wjr0x4qfegn6","channel":"/meta/subscribe","id":"4","subscription":"/s/notifications/readstate","error":"400::The
> channel you requested to subscribe to does not exist
> {/s/notifications/readstate}","successful":false}

I have looked here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/streaming_error_codes.htm at the code and the remedy suggested is

> The streaming channel requested to subscribe to doesn’t exist. Ensure
> that the channel is created before subscribing.

The thing that confuses me is I am not trying to subscribe to '{/s/notifications/readstate}'

My channel name is '/topic/ProjecttaskUpdatesAll'.

If anyone can explain why I get this error it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

To subscribe to or publish messages to Salesforce custom platform events, you must configure permissions in your Salesforce environment.

1. Log in to Salesforce.
2. Under Administer on the left pane, click Manage Users --> Profiles, and click on the user profile name for which you want to assign permissions.
3. Edit the profile to assign **object
   permissions** to the Salesforce custom platform event that you
   created.